# How to correctly combine xpath conditions

Tags: html, xpath

I want to select a list of nodes that have class 'product-list-content':

```
//*[@class='product-list-content']
```

and contain text 'Sun 14 June':

```
//*[text()[contains(., 'Sun 14 June')]]
```

But when I combine those two conditions in a single Xpath expression:

```
//*[@class='product-list-content' and text()[contains(., 'Sun 14 June')]]
```

it doesn't work(tested in Chrome).

**My question:** Those two conditions select correct nodes and applied separately:
Why `and` operator doesn't work here. How to correctly combine those two conditions to select the nodes I need ?

Example node:

```
<div class="product-list-content ng-binding">Sun 14 June </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I made a mistake with `@class='product-list-content'`. When I replaced it with `contains(@class,'product-list-content')` it started working.

So the correct xpath is:

```
//*[contains(@class,'product-list-content') and contains(text(), 'Sun 14 June')]
```

Comment: `@class="product-list-content ng-binding"` could have worked too.

Comment: @LuisMuñoz yeah, it's just less reliable. `ng-binding` isn't giving me more specificity, but adds dependency on additional class.